# How to convert Java double to byte[], and byte[] to double (IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format)

Tags: java, double, byte, floating-point-conversion

I have 3 methods (1 functional (double to byte[]), and one returning unexpected value (byte[] to double), and 1 method that is functional but performs to many operations to use Hex to double)).

Performance is the utmost importance, so if you have more efficient code, please share.

Functional method converts from double to byte[] getFloat64(11.27d) returns `byte[]=hex string "40268A3D70A3D70A"`:

```
public static byte[] getFloat64(double value)
    {
        final byte[] float64Bytes = new byte[8];
        long double64Long=Double.doubleToLongBits(value);
        float64Bytes[0] = (byte)((double64Long >> 56) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[1] = (byte)((double64Long >> 48) & 0xff);        
        float64Bytes[2] = (byte)((double64Long >> 40) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[3] = (byte)((double64Long >> 32) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[4] = (byte)((double64Long >> 24) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[5] = (byte)((double64Long >> 16) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[6] = (byte)((double64Long >> 8) & 0xff);
        float64Bytes[7] = (byte)((double64Long >> 0) & 0xff);        
        return float64Bytes;
    }
```

Incorrect double value is returned from this byte[] to double method (calling getFloat64(getFloat64(11.27d)) returns 9.338087023E-315):

```
public static double getFloat64(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble((long)((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 56) 
            | ((bytes[1] & 0xFF) << 48) 
            | ((bytes[2] & 0xFF) << 40) 
            | ((bytes[3] & 0xFF) << 32)
            | ((bytes[4] & 0xFF) << 24) 
            | ((bytes[5] & 0xFF) << 16) 
            | ((bytes[6] & 0xFF) << 8) 
            | ((bytes[7] & 0xFF) << 0)); 
    }
```

The final method returns the correct answer calling getFloat64("40268A3D70A3D70A") returns 11.27:

```
public double getFloat64(String hex_double)
    {
       long longBits = Long.valueOf(hex_double,16).longValue(); 
       return Double.longBitsToDouble(longBits);
    }
```

What is wrong with the middle method? Why does it not behave like the last method by returning 11.27?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `(bytes[0] & 0xFF)` is still a 32-bit integer value. If you bit-shift it 56 bits to the left on a 32-bit value, Java shifts by `56 % 32 = 24` bits instead of 56 bits.

You first need to promote the value to 64-bit long before bit-shifting it. One way to do that is to `&` with a long value (`0xFFL`). Any integral number-literal (that ordinarily has the type `int` and hence 32 bits) can be turned into a long-literal by appending `L` or `l` to it.

Corrected code:

```
public static double getFloat64(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return Double.longBitsToDouble(((bytes[0] & 0xFFL) << 56) 
            | ((bytes[1] & 0xFFL) << 48) 
            | ((bytes[2] & 0xFFL) << 40) 
            | ((bytes[3] & 0xFFL) << 32)
            | ((bytes[4] & 0xFFL) << 24) 
            | ((bytes[5] & 0xFFL) << 16) 
            | ((bytes[6] & 0xFFL) << 8) 
            | ((bytes[7] & 0xFFL) << 0)); 
    }
```

ob-JLS reference: [Java Language Specification 15.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator `&` (§15.22.1) with the mask value `0x1f`
>   (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Comment: Can you explain how appending the `L` literal affects the the value of `0xFF`

Comment: The point is that the shifts all need to be done using `long` operations, but the original version uses `int` operations.

Comment: So `0xFF` is inherently an integer, similar to writing `255` instead of `255L`?

Comment: @mrres1 Yes, that's correct. Any integral number literal is ordinarily a 32-bit int, unless you explicitly turn it into a long with `l` or `L` suffix (or cast it with `((long) 0xFF)`.

Comment: I've been coding in Java for 20 years, and I just learned something new:) Thanks Erwin!

Comment: @AaronSims I missed one thing about shifting more than 32 bits, it doesn't shift bits completely out of the register but takes your shift value modulo 32. Doesn't change the fix but useful to know. Updated answer.